# tomcat-users.xml will not open in UBUNTU

Tags: java, xml, apache, tomcat, ubuntu

I am trying to log into the host manager , but I am unable to open the tomcat-users.xm file. When I right click it to open in editor it says permission denied.

```
Could not open the file /etc/tomcat6/tomcat-users.xml.

You do not have the permissions necessary to open the file.
```

The owner is root and I even tried doing some " sudo s " cmd to change my role.

I even tried emailing myself the file to another machine but the file wont email or zip up.

Comment: Try `sudo chmod 777 /etc/tomcat6/tomcat-users.xml` first.

Comment: please add that as an answer so I can give you credit. I searched google for the last two hours and wish this would of been on here to test against. Thanks!

Comment: Actually that let me open it but not edit. ould not create a backup file while saving /etc/tomcat6/tomcat-users.xml

Comment: Try running your file editor with `sudo`. For example, if your file editor is `vim`, from the command line you can type `sudo vim my_file`.

Comment: @ndesign11 Glad that helped. I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `sudo chmod 777 /etc/tomcat6/tomcat-users.xml` first. If you want to edit it, you may need to `sudo` that too: eg. `sudo vim /etc/tomcat6/tomcat-users.xml`.

Comment: I'm on Debian and this command says: sudo: vim: command not found. It's worked: http://askubuntu.com/a/147640/423103

Answer (score 0):

**sudo chmod 777 /etc/tomcat6/tomcat-users.xml** on ubuntu. just go back to your tomcat-users.xml file and double click, you will see it you have permission now.